# Return Result_ok on back button hit (from android default Add Contact Screen ) at the time of storing contacts using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-contacts

I tried to store contact using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                    ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,
                    "Contact name here");
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY,
                    "Company Name");
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL,
                    "someemailid@gmail.com");
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,
                    "9999999999");
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
                intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

now from contact screen if i select discard or revert i got RESULT_CANCELLED onacitivityresult but why m gtting result_ok on back button hit .And one more issue is
 in 4.2 if i minimize app(recent apps button tap) contact will be stored without tapping on done or back pressed.
tried with normal activity class (without default intent action)  its working fine return cancelled on back button hit i want same behavior for the contact intent. on back button hit it should return result_cancelled.

[image: when i hit most recent app]

contact saved on  app minimize

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what your problem is. Is your problem that when hitting the back button you receive a RESULT_CANCELLED in your onActivityResult callback?

Comment: That is the expected result. If a user hits the back button it means they want to go back which implies cancel the current operation.

Comment: srry by mistake i post last comment... actually it returns result_ok on back button hit from Add Contact Screen. Srry 4 the last comment..

Answer (score 1):

Probably, because [`ContactEditorActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/master/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ContactEditorActivity.java) is overriding back key and saving the current contact:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mFragment.save(SaveMode.CLOSE);
}
```

**Update for:**

```
"its also storing contact on minimizing the app"
```

When an app is minimized its `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods will be called. In your case, the contact gets stored because [`ContactEditorFragment`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/master/src/com/android/contacts/editor/ContactEditorFragment.java) is saving the data in `onStop()`:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAggregationSuggestionEngine != null) {
        mAggregationSuggestionEngine.quit();
    }

    // If anything was left unsaved, save it now but keep the editor open.
    if (!getActivity().isChangingConfigurations() && mStatus == Status.EDITING) {
        save(SaveMode.RELOAD);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thnks for the reply :) , is it poss to get result cancelled on back button hit ? i mean alternate way ? & its also storing contact on minimizing the app (while selecting recent app button of device ) in 4.2

Comment: @user1140237: I think, you should not be expecting `RESULT_CANCELED` once the contact is saved. So, that's normal. For the second part of your question, please see the update.

Comment: i check the code in contact app... & i can understand tht thy are storing it bt can we have alt sol for tht ...? hw to prevent tht behavior ?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no way to prevent that behavior at this moment.

Comment: ok @shoerat thanks for your help :) .. nw i'll create own design layout to add contacts without using default intent.